# Does the operating system design use knowledge of compilation principles?

Tags: compiler-construction, operating-system

One of my teachers said that the design of the operating system uses knowledge of syntax trees and automata. I didn't think of where the application was. Does the operating system actually use this knowledge?

Comment: What did he say when you asked him?

Answer (score 3):

In general? No.  But there are exceptions

- firewall rule engines
- some of the protocol of X is generated from abstract cases.
- thunking layers for syscalls are sometimes generated.